# Is there any way to SFTP a file with filename generation includes yyyyMMddHHmmss

Tags: java

I'm trying to SFTP a file and its filename includes `yyyyMMddHHmmss`.
Once file generated I need to SFTP to remote server and since there is a time difference between the file generation time and the time I'm trying to SFTP, I'm getting (No such file or directory) error.
 ex.

File1 : Extract_20181227172954.txt

My sftp code is trying to find the file with file name:

Extract_20181227173000.txt

```
//file generation

File = getFilePath() + "Extract_"+  + this.getFileDate2() + ".txt";

PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(File);

//Extract_20181227172954.txt  --sample file extracted

 //sftp method

     public boolean upload( String filePath, String fileName) {
        JSch jSch = new JSch();
            File localFile = new File(filePath + fileName);
            this.channelSftp.put(new FileInputStream(localFile), localFile.getName());

    }

//sftp is trying to find file Extract_20181227173000.txt instead of Extract_20181227172954.txt


//calling the sftp method       
 this.sftpSucess = sftp.upload(getFilePath(), "Extract_"+  + getFileDate2() + ".txt");

 //filedate method

SimpleDateFormat fileDate2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");

     private String getFileDate2() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        return this.fileDate2.format(calendar.getTime());
    }
```

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with SFTP. Note that JSch SFTP API takes `InputStream` not a filename. JSch is not aware of your file name at all. -- All your question is about is finding the right local file. And you didn't tell us anything about that part. How can you identify that file? Is there only a single file in the folder? Or do you want to pick the latest file in the folder? Or what?

Comment: Apologies on the Jsch confusion. The file is identified via the generated via name ex. Extract_20181227172954.txt . The file is generated once daily. And i need to pick the exact file based on the filename generated. Note that the filename is based on the timestamp and since there is a difference between the time when the file is generated and the time when i'm trying to SFTP the file,im unable to get the file to sftp, due to filename difference.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the `getFileDate2()`, you are using `Calendar.getInstance()`, for each time you do that you get the current time. Calling it on the second time the file is not found, since the time used in the file name is in the past and you got a most recent time.

You should call the `Calendar.getInstance()` **once** and store the date in your object instead of getting an new instance every time. With the stored date you will be able to fetch the saved file.

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance()):

> getInstance(): Gets a
>   calendar using the default time zone and locale. **The Calendar returned
>   is based on the current time** in the default time zone with the default
>   locale. Returns: a Calendar.

Comment: Yes, i noticed that as well. I'm new to java so please bear with me. Is it a good practice to create a public variable to store the filename (getFileDate2()) on my extraction class , then call that variable on the other class (FTP class)? Or any better practice.

Comment: Since you will need to reuse the file, It would be good to have a class containing the properties you need, like filename, path and so on, and use it in your methods, so you don't need to evaluate every time to build your filename.

Comment: Actually i do have property class. But since part of the filename is the timestamp, i created a method to get it and include in the filename.Currently ,i'm storing the filename in a String Variable named File. It is a local variable in my extraction method. Should i just store it as Public  instance Variable in my extraction class , so i can call it in my FTP class?